# Selected item gets multiplied in DDL items

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I would like to ask for your assistance in resolving the issue I am encountering.

My problem is, the drop down list will show 2 items of SAMPLE (product 2) instead of Test and Sample because the product associated with the orderID 1 is the product 2.

But if i change the productID in OrdersTable from 2 to 1, everything will be displayed correctly. Why is that?

OrdersTable

```
OrderID      ProductID
1            2
```

ProductsTable

```
ProductID    ProductName
1            Test
2            Sample
```

ASP.NET codes

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetOrders();
        GetProducts();
    }
}
private void GetOrders()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string SQL = 
        "SELECT o.OrderID, o.ProductID, p.ProductName FROM Orders AS o, Products AS p WHERE o.ProductID = p.ProductID";

    com.CommandText = SQL;
    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (data.Read())
    {
        ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text = data["ProductName"].ToString();     
    }
}
private void GetProducts()
{
    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con1;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText =
        "SELECT * FROM Products";

    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();

    ddlProduct.DataSource = data;
    ddlProduct.DataValueField = "ProductID";
    ddlProduct.DataTextField = "ProductName";
    ddlProduct.DataBind();

    data.Close();
    con1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting both items changed to `Sample` when the `ProductID` in the `Orders` table is set to 2 is because the initial `SelectedItem` is the first item in the list; the user has not done anything to the page yet. Thus when the following logic executes:

```
while (data.Read())
{
    ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text = data["ProductName"].ToString();     
}
```

The `ddlProduct.SelectedItem` is the first item in the drop down list and the query to the database returned `Sample` as the product name to apply to the selected item's `Text` property and does nothing to the second item in the list which already has a text value of `Sample`; therefore now both items in the drop down list have the same `Sample` text value.

Your "problem" is that the initial selected item in the drop down list is the first item in the list even though the user technically has not selected an item at all. I am not sure what behavior you are really even after here; the user selects an item from the drop down list and the text of the item they selected potentially changes?

Comment: What I want to happen here is that the user can change his selected product. For example, current product in orders table is sample, when the interface loads up, ddl should be set to the item that the user has chosen. But it should also load all products from products table so as to have choices if the user needs to change his order.

Comment: I still do not understand why the initial load of the data when page is not a post back is setting the `ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Text` instead of just binding the drop down list with product names. It would seem from that loading of the product names that now when the user changes the selected item in the drop down list that some logic in the event handler would load data for display in another control, like details about the product selected, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, i got confused. But if the user changes his selected product, nothing should happen like it will show the details of it. Only the selecteditem.value is important since that corresponds to the productID.